# Crystal Reports 2008 deployment

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports-2008

I am new to crystal reports so this may be a simple question for experts ( I am hoping so ), I have an existing report that I added a data field to from an existing view. I had to add this field to the view so in the old report and on the production SQL server the data field did not exist. The report is running on my local machine connected to a local copy of the production SQL database and it works.

My question is how do I deploy this to the production server? I've only worked with Crystal 2008 for around one day but I am seeing how you have to verify the database just to get it to run locally, I cant do this on the production server, Crystal Reports development environment is not on the production server ( for good reason ) and I cannot connect to the production SQL database from my local machine to verify the datasource. I'm sure I am over thinking this but I don't see how this will work if I just copy the file over as is without verifying the datasource.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: What do you currently use to run the report (in prod)?  CR server, a ASP.NET app, or a desktop (winforms) app?

Comment: Its run thru a VB6 app :/

Comment: What I am running into is issues changing the datasource location, Its on a production server that I dont have access to from here.

Comment: The answer depends: a VB6 app (if written well) should open the report and change the connection, via code. However, some apps don't. By default, the program can count on the report to already point to the right DB server.  Can you ask the programmer, or look at the code that runs the report?

Comment: Programmer passed away unfortunately. I did look at the code that opens it and it appears to apply connection properties. I'll see if I can get it to work without verifying the test DB.

Comment: Sorry to hear about your programmer.  By your description, it sounds like it should work by just putting the new file over the old one.  (after backing-up the original file, of course).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it shot and let you know.

Comment: It failed trying to connect to my local database. Im trying to get a vpn connection so I can connect to it directly from Crystal.